# Как сделать, чтобы в коде в функции print параметр end был всегда равен пустой строке

Tags: python

Как сделать, чтобы в коде в функции `print` параметр `end` был всегда равен пустой строке (`''`)?

Comment: Так в скоупе принта присвойте вашему параметру пустую строку и после  используйте его там где и собирались.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете сделать свою функцию для печати:

```
def my_print(*args):
    print(*args, end='')


my_print(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
my_print(6, 7, 8)
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно заменить настоящий `print` своим, вот так:

```
old_print = print

def new_print(*args, **kwargs):
    kwargs['end'] = ''
    old_print(*args, **kwargs)

print = new_print

print('abc')
print('123')
print('!')
# abc123!
```

Передавать `kwargs` нужно, чтобы была возможность передавать следующие именованные аргументы `print`:

- `sep=' '`
- `end='\n'`
- `file=None`

Пример:

```
print('abc')
print('123')
print('!')
print(*'abc', sep='|')
# abc123!a|b|c
```